# jQuery Ajax .ajaxSuccess() event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a native JavaScript object, that I would like to assign the `.ajaxSuccess` callback to. The purpose of this is because I want my data model to update after an ajax call succeeds, but I don't want to make my data model global to the entire JavaScript file. And yes, I checked to make sure my jQuery is included before my script file.

Here is the code:

```
$("#formButtonAddLink").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/addlink",
        data: {content: $("#formInputLinkContent").val(), subject: $("#formInputLinkSubject").val()},
        dataType: "json",
        error: function() {
            alert("An ajax error occured adding link")
        }
    });
    return false; //prevents html form submit
})

$(document).ready(function(){
    var links = new Links(20,0);
    $(links).ajaxSuccess(function() {
        console.log("Hey.")    //This does not work.
    });
    $(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
        console.log("Document hey.")   //This shows up.
    });
});
```

Comment: That is completely invalid.  What exactly is your desired result?  If I remember correctly, the jquery object which `ajaxSuccess` is called on has no real effect, so why not just use `document` or anything else for that matter.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Which parts are invalid? The desired result is for my links object to receive the .ajaxSuccess callback. In reality it will do something more useful than console.log. I want my links object to update itself after the ajax call which is why I can't use any ol' DOM object

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#working-with-plain-objects.  The object you call `ajaxSuccess` on doesn't "receive" anything.  If you want to use the `links` variable inside the callback, you can do so.

Comment: So the api that says "jQuery( object ), object: A plain object to wrap in a jQuery object" doesn't work in this case?

Comment: Updated my comment.  See the link.  But your overall understanding of what `ajaxSuccess` does seems to be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea of `ajaxSuccess()` is:

> Whenever an Ajax request completes successfully, jQuery triggers the
>   ajaxSuccess event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with
>   the .ajaxSuccess() method are executed at this time.

As far as I understand it from the [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsuccess/) you can only attach the `ajaxSuccess()` event  handler to an **element**, not a JavaScript object. That is why it works when attaching the event handler to the `document`.

> We can attach our event handler to any element.

In this case if you have something similar to:

```
<div class="links"></div>
```

You could do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".links").ajaxSuccess(function() {
        console.log("Hey.")
        // use links in here:
        var links = new Links(20,0);
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. I was hoping to bind the callback on the object itself but I guess that's not possible. So I will bind it to a relevant element and then handle things from there. Thanks!

Comment: As of jQuery 1.9, all the handlers for the jQuery global Ajax events, including those added with the .ajaxSuccess() method, must be attached to document.